# Refactoring from js to tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in React I'm trying to rewrite js components to in tsx components. Therefore I'm simply converting PropTypes into TypeScript "types". Just getting started with TS, I'm producing plenty of errors "does not exist" (ts2339) and "is missing in type" (ts2741)

my old (js) file:

```
    import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { Close as CloseIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

function AboutDialog(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dialogProps = props.dialogProps;
  const user = props.user;
  const version = process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION;

  if (!user && !version) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth="xs" {...dialogProps}>
      <DialogTitle disableTypography>
        <Typography variant="h6">
          About {process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}
        </Typography>

        <Tooltip title="Close">
          <IconButton
            className={classes.closeButton}
            onClick={dialogProps.onClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent>
        <List disablePadding>
          {version && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="Version" secondary={version} />
            </ListItem>
          )}

          {user && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="UID" secondary={user.uid} />
            </ListItem>
          )}
        </List>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

AboutDialog.propTypes = {
  dialogProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  user: PropTypes.object,
};

export default AboutDialog;
```

my new (tsx) file:

```
import React from "react";

import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { Close as CloseIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

type AboutDialogProps = {
  dialogProps: object;
  user?: object;
};

const AboutDialog: React.FC<AboutDialogProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dialogProps = props.dialogProps;
  const user = props.user;
  const version = process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION;

  if (!user && !version) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth="xs" {...dialogProps}>
      <DialogTitle disableTypography>
        <Typography variant="h6">
          About {process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}
        </Typography>

        <Tooltip title="Close">
          <IconButton
            className={classes.closeButton}
            onClick={dialogProps.onClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent>
        <List disablePadding>
          {version && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="Version" secondary={version} />
            </ListItem>
          )}

          {user && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="UID" secondary={user.uid} />
            </ListItem>
          )}
        </List>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default AboutDialog;
```

Error 1:
Property 'open' is missing in type '{ children: Element[]; fullWidth: true; maxWidth: "xs"; }' but required in type 'DialogProps'.ts(2741)
Dialog.d.ts(88, 3): 'open' is declared here.

Error 2:
Property 'onClose' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

Error 3:
Property 'uid' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

Trying to fix stuff in the other components just produces more mistakes. What am I conceptually failing to understand here? // How would you go about converting/refactoring it?

UPDATE after fix from the first two comments (Mar 21st):
import React from "react";

```
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  DialogProps,
} from "@material-ui/core";

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import { Close as CloseIcon } from "@material-ui/icons";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing(1),
    top: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));

interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  emailVerified: string;
  password: string;
  displayName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  disabled: string;
};

interface AboutDialogProps {
  dialogProps?: DialogProps;
  user?: User;
  onClose: () => void;
};

const AboutDialog = (props: AboutDialogProps) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dialogProps = props.dialogProps;
  const user = props.user;
  const version = process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION;

  if (!user && !version) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Dialog fullWidth maxWidth="xs" {...dialogProps}>
      <DialogTitle disableTypography>
        <Typography variant="h6">
          About {process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE}
        </Typography>

        <Tooltip title="Close">
          <IconButton
            className={classes.closeButton}
            onClick={dialogProps.onClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent>
        <List disablePadding>
          {version && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="Version" secondary={version} />
            </ListItem>
          )}

          {user && (
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemText primary="UID" secondary={user.uid} />
            </ListItem>
          )}
        </List>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default AboutDialog;
```

This throws new errors on IconButton:
"
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(props: { href: string; } & { color?: Color | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; edge?: false | "end" | "start" | undefined; size?: "medium" | "small" | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
Type '((event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.
Type '(event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(props: { component: ElementType; } & { color?: Color | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; edge?: false | "end" | "start" | undefined; size?: "medium" | "small" | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: Element; className: string; onClick: ((event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => void) | undefined; }' but required in type '{ component: ElementType; }'.
Overload 3 of 3, '(props: DefaultComponentProps<ExtendButtonBaseTypeMap<IconButtonTypeMap<{}, "button">>>): Element', gave the following error.
Type '((event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.
Type '(event: {}, reason: "backdropClick" | "escapeKeyDown") => void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(1449, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; } & { color?: Color | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; edge?: false | "end" | "start" | undefined; size?: "medium" | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
OverridableComponent.d.ts(17, 7): 'component' is declared here.
index.d.ts(1449, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { color?: Color | undefined; disableFocusRipple?: boolean | undefined; edge?: false | "end" | "start" | undefined; size?: "medium" | "small" | undefined; } & { ...; } & CommonProps<...> & Pick<...>'
"

... and on Dialog:
"
Type '{ children: Element[]; 'aria-describedby'?: string | undefined; 'aria-labelledby'?: string | undefined; disableBackdropClick?: boolean | undefined; disableEscapeKeyDown?: boolean | undefined; ... 285 more ...; classes?: Partial<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'DialogProps'.
Types of property 'open' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
"

Comment: also, the npm packages available for transforming js to typescript seem to have very few downloads (e.g. react-proptypes-to-typescript or react-js-to-ts). i guess plenty of people must have similar problems converting js to ts, can you recomnmend anything than automizes it?

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is strongly types language.
Let's focus on Errors:

1. open is untype.
2. onClose is untype.
3. uid is untype.

It's object so i suggest to create interface IOpen:

```
interface IOpen {
 children: Array<Element>
 fullWidth: boolean;
 maxWidth: string
}
```

onClose - there is probably need type:

```
onClose: () => void
```

uid - there is probably need type - i seen that uid is **string** inside user **object**. So there is possiblity to add another interface:

```
interface IUser {
 (...)
 uid:string
 (...)
}
```

In your case you type user like **object** and it's true - but the ts compiler require more specific informations.

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure i understand 100%. I edited the file above. is the onClose type implemented correctly?

the interface IOpen should then be imported from material-ui (as also done in the edited solution above)?

Comment: If it’s part of library so it’s should include type for it

Comment: hah - welcome in the dark side of typescript

Comment: just went thru the materialUI docs for implementing TS again. It gets more painful: https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/ :) still not working i think the best way is just to leave existing js(x) files as is and add TS only to the new components...

Answer (score 0):

You want to be a bit more specific than "object" when you define your types.
Something like this should work

```
type User = {
    uid: string;
    //add all the property of your user
};

type AboutDialogProps = {
    dialogProps: DialogProps; //DialogProps is imported from @material-ui/core
    user?: User;
};
```

Comment: thanks, this fixed part of it, but produced some new errors also. how do you guys generally go about it. this is the first of 25 files to be refactored to TS and it is taking a few hours of reading up on errors. can I just leave the existing files in JS and build with TS in the new files? 
would that imply simply defining interfaces/types in the new files if they use parts of the old JS files and everything should run smothly?